# Cannot get a crontab to run a ruby script on a raspberrpi

Tags: ruby, cron, raspberry-pi

Hey guys I am having trouble getting a ruby script to run on a cronjob. The cron is below

```
*/1 * * * * '/usr/bin/ruby ~/MiningMonitorClient/push.rb test worker1'
```

I am trying to run push.rb with options test & worker1 every minute. But its not running the script and I'm not sure why! This is being run on a raspberrpi with ruby installed and the script runs fine outside of the cron.

Here is the cron being run

```
  Jun 28 03:43:01 raspberrypi /USR/SBIN/CRON[19966]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/ruby ~/MiningMonitorClient/push.rb test worker1)
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any `cron` that wants a single quoted string as the command name. I'd guess that cron is trying to run:

```
'/usr/bin/ruby ~/MiningMonitorClient/push.rb test worker1'
```

as a command and failing because there is no such command. Drop the single quotes:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/ruby ~/MiningMonitorClient/push.rb test worker1
```

Also, as noted by [tadman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87189/tadman), cron (or `/bin/sh` which mostly likely is ultimately responsible for running that command) might not understand that `~` means "home directory" so try expanding the `~` manually:

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/ruby /home/whoever_you_are/MiningMonitorClient/push.rb test worker1
```

Comment: I tried doing that and it still didn't work. I see the Cron being run but I dont think its executing the script.

Comment: Why don't you think it is running your script? Any error messages anywhere?

Comment: How can I view messages? if it was running I would see an put update to a website I'm working on and I'm not seeing it

Comment: Is there anything in the syslog? Try replacing your script with something that just touches a `/tmp` file, that should help you isolate the problem.

Comment: I posted the syslog above with the cron being run.

Comment: Thats a good suggestion I'll try adding the full path to the script.

Comment: THANK YOU TADMAN you fixed my issue!